# Creating 2D matrix from the "cut" of a 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

I have a 3D matrix `ch4_global` `180 by 360 by 452` (latitude by longitude by time). I want to create a 2D matrix from the cut of the 3D matrix. The cut matrix is a 2D matrix(`id`) of size 451 by 1. I need to cut `ch4_global` (180x360) using `id` for each time.

```
id=find(Latitude<=-10.5 & Latitude>=-20.5 & Longitude<=-35.5 & Longitude>=-75.5);
```

So, I want:

```
co(:,time)=ch4_global(id,time)
```

Comment: If ch4_global is 3D, then how does this work: `ch4_global(id,time)`?    And `id` is not a 2D matrix, it's a vector.  Your question isn't clear

Comment: @IGOR - Please provide a small numeric example of what you want to do (using e.g. a 3x3x3 matrix). Also, why is `id` shorter than `size(ch4_global,3)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the examples (and array sizes) given in your question, I'm assuming you're working in the `[elevation <=> θ <=> latitude, azimuth <=> φ <=> longitude]` convention for spherical coordinates:

[image: Spherical coordinates in physics; From Wikipedia]

... and the positions in the array correspond to the appropriate **angles in degrees**. For this reason I'm thinking you can get what you want by simple indexing of a sub-array:

```
cut_ch4_global = ch4_global( (-20:-11)+90, (-75:-35)+180, :);
```

Note that the result is still a 3D array, but now it only contains the lat/lng you're interested in (if my assumptions are correct).

I apologize in advance for any "off-by-1" errors.

Answer (score 2):

[`squeeze`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) will do the trick for you.

```
A = rand(180,360,452);
B = squeeze(A(:,:,1));
```

Comment: Hi Adrian, but no is considered the matrix "id".

Comment: @IGOR and no is me writing your code. Read the documentation I linked and study the example I provided and write the code. `squeeze` is *the* way to cut out slices of a higher-dimensional matrix.